# Перекрытие дочерних элементов

Tags: c#, maui

Есть `Border`, а в нём `Grid`.

Я передпологал, если я установлю для `Bordrer` свойство `BackgroundColor`, то перекроется и `Grid`, но оказалось что это работает по другому...

Познакомился ещё с `ZIndex`, но как я понял, он на отдельных элементах работает.

Какие есть способы перекрытия ?

Цель, наложить цвет с прозрачностью на элемент в CollectionView - как будто выделение.

Comment: `<Grid><Grid>1</Grid><Border/></Grid>`, то есть, не "а в нем", а "рядом с ним". Скажем так, вы помещаете в некий контейнер, слоями, два независимых друг от друга контрола, которым задаете нужные цвета, прозрачность, и так далее.

Comment: о чем речь? WPF? Так есть же вроде ListView и ListBox или что-то такое, что поддерживает выделение элемента нативно.

Comment: @aepot .NET MAUI

Comment: @aepot CollectionView в MAUI - но я что то ужиться с MAUI не могу) Одна кодовая база - а выделение по клику на элемент на Windows не просходит - ничего не выделяется, а на Android происходит)

Comment: MAUI сыровато пока, могут быть баги. Накиньте стилей с тригерами на выделение, возможно проблема как раз в них.

Comment: @aepot я просто в WinForms ковырялся и в консоли. Но как я понял - MAUI типа заменяет всё перепрыгивая WPF / UWP и стоит осваивать... Просто все эти привязки / команды / тригеры / MVVM и т.д. для меня в новинку.

Comment: Не думаю, что MAUI заменит например WPF, ибо WPF это отличная вещь, созданная исключительно для десктопа, винды, в нем есть все то, что нужно, не занимает много места, не имеет лишнего, может позволить сделать простой .exe, и так далее. А вот MAUI... Он требует для разработки SDK других OS, которые мне, как Windows разработчику не нужны, мне не нужна кросплатформенность. .exe простое сделать там тоже пока весьма не просто, ну и так далее. MAUI хорош тем, что он впитывает в себя то, что нравиться многим в WPF/XAMARIN и так далее, в плане обучения он будет оч полезен, но как замена.. Пока нет.